# Terminating all child threads on closing the stage/window

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have multiple instances of child threads which are started and should continue to execute in till the applications exits.

I have classes which extends Task and I create the threads as

```
new Thread(object of the class).start();
```

All the threads should be terminated on closing of the primary stage.

```
primaryStage.onCloseOperation(){...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `ExecutorService` which has a `ThreadFactory` to create daemon threads.

For example :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
     @Override
     public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        return thread;
     }
});
```

and the rest how to use it has already been said by @Enno.

Thanks Enno :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd manage your threads explicitly from the beginning. In particular, have a thread pool in your parent class like so:

```
ExecutionService exec = Executors.newCachedExecutionService();
```

then, if your tasks are meant to keep running (instead of being periodically scheduled) code your tasks responsive to interruption like so:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    do stuff;
}
```

This will make the task run until interrupted. It is important in this case that you never ignore an `InterruptedException`, because `InterruptedException` set `isInterrupted` to false when they are thrown. Do this when you see an `InterruptedException`:

```
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    return;
}
```

Then, you can start your child tasks like so:

```
for(task : tasks){
    exec.execute(task);
}
```

Now, when your parent task finishes, you can simply call:

```
exec.shutdownNow();
```

To stop your child tasks. If your child tasks use `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`, you must use `shutdownNow()` (`shutdown()` only works if you want to wait for tasks to stop by themselves).

Comment: How do i create new thread using ExecutorService ? Or any thread created created automatically fall into ExecutorService ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: ah sorry forgot to mention how to start the tasks. Edited it in now. The threads will be managed by the executor service, yes.

Comment: Actually i was starting new threads in different classes, should I pass a reference of "exec" to the constructor of the classes ? Or this would again be a bad design ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: That is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of using `ThreadGroup` to group all the threads and then controlling their behavior. Java 5 added the ThreadInfo and ThreadMXBean classes in java.lang.management to get state information.

Here is a sample example to achieve this using tutorial available herehttp://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/java_tip_how_list_and_find_threads_and_thread_groups:

**Getting a list of all threads**

Another enumerate( ) method on a ThreadGroup lists that group's threads. With a true second argument, it will recursively traverse the group to fill a given array with Thread objects. Start at the root ThreadGroup and you'll get a list of all threads in the JVM.

The problem here is the same as that for listing thread groups. If the array you pass to enumerate( ) is too small, some threads might be silently dropped from the returned array. So, you'll need to take a guess at the array size, call enumerate( ), check the returned value, and try again if the array filled up. To get a good starting guess, look to the java.lang.management package. The ManagementFactory class there returns a ThreadMXBean who's getThreadCount( ) method returns the total number of threads in the JVM. Of course, this can change a moment later, but it's a good first guess.

```
Thread[] getAllThreads( ) {
    final ThreadGroup root = getRootThreadGroup( );
    final ThreadMXBean thbean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( );
    int nAlloc = thbean.getThreadCount( );
    int n = 0;
    Thread[] threads;
    do {
        nAlloc *= 2;
        threads = new Thread[ nAlloc ];
        n = root.enumerate( threads, true );
    } while ( n == nAlloc );
    return java.util.Arrays.copyOf( threads, n );
}
```